# Get-ChildItem to a specific level of folders

Tags: powershell

So I have a folder structure similar to the below:

```
\\server\drive\code\serverName
```

If I run a `Get-ChildItem` on the `\\server\drive` it will return:

```
\\server\drive\code\
\\server\drive\code\serverName
```

(and a lot more results, this is just an example)

I only care about the the:

```
\\server\drive\code\serverName
```

So am I left with list of servers utilising storage on that drive - as I will be using this to work out how much storage each server is using.

How can I use `GCI` to just get the `\\server\drive\code\serverName` folders and ignore the parent folders `\\server\drive\code\`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar conclusion with count. My solution is slightly different.

```
$basePath = "c:\temp"
$baseLevels = $basePath.Split("\").Count - 1
$levelsDeep = 2
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $basePath | Where-Object{(($_.FullName).Split("\").Count - $baseLevels - 1) -eq $levelsDeep}
```

The variables `$basePath`,`$baseLevels` and `$levelsDeep` make this a little more dynamic. Take the `$basePath` and count how many levels it is so that our calculations are based of `$levelsDeep` from `$basePath`. So this would return all directories that are `2` levels deep from `C:\temp`

The `-1` in both calculation is a means to ignore the drive, which in my case is C:\, since that is not a "folder"

Comment: Nice solution! Certainly more dynamic then my own

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following solution for anyone interested. The only easy way I could think of doing this was to count the number of "\" contained in each line via regex.

```
ForEach($var in $path.FullName){    
    If(([regex]::matches($($var),"\\").count) -eq 4){ 
        #Ignored as this is first parent level folder         
    }else{
        $var >> C:\Paths.txt
    }
}
```